# File not found error when copying images from one folder to another

Tags: python, path, copy

I have a text file containing the names of images to be copied from a source folder to a destination folder. The source folder contains several sub-folders as shown below. The images may come from any of these sub-folders.

```
animals (source folder)
|-cats_1 
|-cats_2 
|-tigers_1 
|-lions_1 
|-lions_2
```

Shown below is the Python code:

```
import os
import shutil
src = r'X:\animals' #source with multiple sub-folders
dest = r'X:\images\cat_family' #destination folder
with open('cat_fam.txt') as file: #text file containing the image names
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for name in file:
        file_name  = name.strip()
        filename = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        shutil.copy2(filename, dest)
```

I encounter a file not found error as shown below:

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\2/ipykernel_30556/2100413787.py", line 6, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(filename, dest)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\shutil.py", line 266, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'X:\\animals\\lion_2345.jpg'
```

Comment: It appears that 'X:\\animals\\lion_2345.jpg' doesn't exist. Also, that's not valid Python code. The % characters will cause a SyntaxError. My is that it's in either lions_1 or lions_2

Comment: @Pingu: I agree! I had Matlab in my mind and added those captions with "%" when posting the code here. The file not found error is because it is checking in the source folder "animals" but not in any of the sub-folders. I have to modify the "filename" to check all the sub-folders. Need assistance to change the code in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to build a dictionary out of the data returned from os.walk()

The dictionary will be keyed on filename (not the full path) and its value will be the directory where the file resides.

Then you can read the cat_fam.txt file and lookup in the dictionary to see where it exists (if it exists!)

```
from os.path import join
from os import walk
from shutil import copy2

src = r'X:\animals'
dest = r'X:\animals\cat_family'
db = dict()
for root, _, files in walk(src):
    for file in files:
        db[file] = root
with open('cat_fam.txt') as fam:
    for cat in map(str.strip, fam):
        fp = db.get(cat)
        if fp is not None:
            copy2(join(fp, cat), join(dest, cat))
```

Comment: I get a syntax error at "if fp := db.get(cat):" Thanks.

Comment: @shiva That's because you're using an outdated version of Python. This code relies on 3.8+ due to the assignment expression (a.k.a. walrus operator). I'll edit the code but you really should bring your Python environment up-to-date. 3.11.1 is the latest

Comment: That is so kind of you! It worked! MY DL environment is tied to this version of Python (3.7.11). Sure, I will follow your suggestions and use the newer one for my future project.